# Create foldable template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

### Question

Is it possible to create foldable (※ [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)) template [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

#### Example

Consider the following example (function that takes two arguments of type `int` ([decayed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay))).

```cpp
template<
    typename L,
    typename R,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same_v<int, std::decay_t<L>>
        &&  std::is_same_v<int, std::decay_t<R>>
    >
>
int F(L Left, R Right){
    return 0x70D0;
}
```

Is it possible to create template parameter pack that can be folded to avoid writing same fragment of code multiple times (*ie* `std::is_same_v`)?

Something that represented as `std::pack` below could simplify using SFINAE?

```cpp
typename = std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<int, std::decay_t<std::pack<L, R>>>)>
```

#### What I've tried

I've tried to solve the problem using `T` pack and aliasing single `L` and `R`.
But for some reaon the following code compiles and runs without an error (second argument of second `F` function call, decayed, does not equal `int`) on MSVC 15.9.4+28307.222:

```cpp
template<
    typename... T,
    typename L = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<T...>>,
    typename R = std::tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<T...>>,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<int, std::decay_t<T>>)>
>
int F(L Left, R Right){
    return 0x70D0;
}

int main(){
    F(3, 5);   // OK
    F(3, "5"); // OK, but should not compile
}
```

PS Also, did I miss something in the above code to make SFINAE work properly (filter functions with `int, int` (decayed) arguments only)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because apparently the OP doesn't want it around anymore?

Comment: @Hans, that's not how SO works.  If the question is on-topic, then it belongs to the SO community.  We don't delete good content like that.

Comment: @TobySpeight I wasn't sure whether to rollback the OP's deletion of the question or VTC - I'll rollback next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to create template parameter pack that can be folded to avoid writing same fragment of code multiple times?

In place? Not in C++17. You would have to wrap your types into some sort of `template <typename...> struct typelist;` and then unwrap them somewhere else. This requires one layer of indirection.

There's no way to write anything like `std::pack` as far as I know.

---

> I've tried to solve the problem using T pack and aliasing single L and R. [...]

In your code, `T...` will always be empty as it's not being deduced by anything. `L` and `R`'s default template parameter values are ignored, as they are being deduced by the function call.

You need something like:

```
template<
    typename... T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<int, T>)>
>
int F(T...){
    return 0x70D0;
}
```

---

In C++20, you should be able to use a lambda as follows:

```
template<
    typename L,
    typename R,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<[]<typename... Ts>(){
        return (... && std::is_same_v<int, Ts>)
    }.operator()<L, R>()>
>
int F(L Left, R Right){
    return 0x70D0;
}
```

Comment: Can drop the `decay_t<T>` since you're taking by value (`decay_t<T>` will just be `T`)

Comment: @Barry: fixed, also added possible C++20 solution.

Comment: lol I'm tempted to remove my upvote for seriously suggesting that one ;-)

Comment: `std::tuple` can be used imaginatively very much like this hypothetical `std::pack`.

Answer (score 2):

Is too late to play ?

> Is it possible to create template parameter pack that can be folded to avoid writing same fragment of code multiple times?

Not in `F()` itself, as far I know.

But you can repack the types, by example, in a list of a called function.

I mean... if you <s>declare</s> define <s>(declare only: there isn't need of define it because is used only in a `decltype()`)</s> the following function [Edit: as suggested by Barry (thanks) defining the function simplify the use]

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto isSameList ()
   -> std::bool_constant<(... && std::is_same_v<T, std::decay_t<Ts>>)>
 { return {}; }
```

where you can use template folding, you can SFINAE to enable/disable `F()` as follows

```
template <typename L, typename R,
          std::enable_if_t<isSameList<int, L, R>(), bool> = true>
int F(L Left, R Right)
 { return 0x70D0; }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto isSameList ()
   -> std::bool_constant<(... && std::is_same_v<T, std::decay_t<Ts>>)>
 { return {}; } 

template <typename L, typename R,
          std::enable_if_t<isSameList<int, L, R>(), bool> = true>
int F(L Left, R Right)
 { return 0x70D0; }

int main ()
 {
    F(3, 5);   // compile
    //F(3, "5"); // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: This pattern works a lot better if you define `isSameList` to return that object, so you can change `decltype(f()){}` to just `f()`

Comment: @Barry - Are you right: so is more simple and elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it:

```
template <typename L,typename R,
  typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::tuple<int,L,R>,std::tuple<L,R,int>>>>
int F(L Left, R Right){
    return 0x70D0;
}

int main(){
    F(3, 5);   // OK
    F(3, "5"); // Does not compile
    F("5", 3); // Does not compile
}
```

or the variadic version:

```
template <typename... T,
  typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::tuple<int,T...>,std::tuple<T...,int>>>>
int F(T... args){
    return 0x70D0;
}

int main(){
    F(3, 5);   // OK
    F(3, "5"); // Does not compile
    F("5", 3); // Does not compile
}
```